# Function to change display to 'block' from 'none' onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a clickable dropdown menu using divs instead of uls. I have everything styled properly, but the function I wrote won't toggle the visibility. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
        <a href="#" name="menu" onclick="toggleMenu('menu-1.sub');"><div class="menu-item" id="menu-1"><a aria-haspopup="true" href="#">GET SUPPORT</a>
            <div class="sub-menu" id="menu-1.sub"></div>
        </div></a>



</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 div#mobile_menu_drop-down_test {display:block; position:absolute; top:35px; 
 left:20px; width:40px; height:40px; box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #000; 
background-color:#fff;  background-image:url(Images/hamburger.png); 
background-size:30px 20px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-
position:center; cursor:pointer;
}

div#mobile_menu_wrapper {
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:auto;
background-color:#ffcb05;
color:#00274c;
box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
}

div.menu-item {
display:block; width:100%; border-bottom:1px dashed #5d5d5d; 
padding:15px 0px; text-indent:30px; transition:.2s ease;
}


div.sub-menu {display:none; text-indent:65px; padding:12px 0px; color:#fff;}


}
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggleMenu (id) {
var men = document.getElementById(id);
if (men.style.display =='none')
    men.style.display = 'block';
else
    men.style.display ='none';
}
```

Comment: Got jsfiddle of that?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't nets links. Browsers will try and compensate for this and rearrange your HTML.

Comment: Nested links is why this won't work, good catch thank you!

p.s. here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tonyprovenzola/qjepcnLs/

Answer (score 1):

You're adding your `display: none;` in your CSS. `element.style.display` checks the inline styles on the element. Change your javascript to this:

```js
var men = document.getElementById(id);
var display = men.currentStyle ? men.currentStyle.display :
                          getComputedStyle(men, null).display;
if (display == 'none' || men.style.display == 'none')
    men.style.display = 'block';
else
    men.style.display = 'none';
}
```

IE uses `.currentStyle`, but other browsers don't (hence the ternary operator). Other browsers use `getComputedStyle()`, so we are using the correct version depending on our browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your css you do not have a rule that defines the element with id "menu-1.sub".

You have a definition for #mobile_menu_drop-down_test and #mobile_menu_wrapper.

In your css file you need to define #menu-1.sub and set it's initial display property to equal 'none'.

Then the function will be able to eventually evaluate men.style.display === 'none' to be true, and will then proceed to set men.style.display property to have the value 'block'.